# Google Maps groundoverlay zoom jumps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

When I zoom out and then zoom on the image overlay, the image moves to another copy of the map. Any suggestions?  Changed the overlay image in Google Map's historical overlay example to NOAA's ocean surface temperature which covers the world.
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple

```
var historicalOverlay;

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: {lat: 0, lng: 0}    
    });
    var imageBounds = {
        north: 79.995,
        south: -79.995,
        east: 179.005,
        west: -178.995
    };

    var overlayOpts ={opacity:1};
    historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
        'https://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/jplG1SST.transparentPng?SST[(2017-01-11T00:00:00Z)][(-79.995):(79.995)][(-178.995):(179.005)]&.draw=surface&.vars=longitude%7Clatitude%7CSST&.colorBar=LightRainbow%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C&.bgColor=0xffccccff',
        imageBounds, overlayOpts);        historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
  }
```